# Does the Arcane Archer fighter's Curving Shot feature require you to see the second creature if you missed the first?

Tags: dnd-5e, class-feature, attack, fighter, vision-and-light

When you miss an attack as an [Arcane Archer fighter](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/fighter#ArcaneArcher), the Curving Shot feature (XGtE, p. 28) lets you use a bonus action to reroll that attack against another creature within 60ft of the first.

> #### Curving Shot
>
> At 7th level, you learn how to direct an errant arrow toward a new target. When you make an attack roll with a magic arrow and miss, you can use a bonus action to reroll the attack roll against a different target within 60 feet of the original target.

Would you need to be able to see the second target when rerolling this attack?

I imagine that if you know the second target is there it would be similar to attacking an invisible target, and thus be with disadvantage.

Would it be possible to hit a second target if you didn't know they were there?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### There is nothing stopping you targeting an unseen target

There is general nor specific rule (i.e. no part of Curving Shot) saying you can't attack someone you can't see. If you know or assume there's a creature (you would like to attack) in certain location, because they went invisible there, you heard them, or you're taking a wild guess, you can attack that location, albeit with disadvantage. The stipulation on you hitting (beyond your rolls) is the target being where you aimed and it not having total cover, although it is not clear from Curving Shot whether the new target needs total cover from you or the missed target. Personally I would rule the latter as the arrow has already missed. See page 194 of the *Player's Handbook* for the rules on 'Unseen Attackers and Targets'. Also of note is that certain spells will explicitly require you to see the target, but if they do it is called out in their description.

Answer (score 4):

The rules of cover state that you cannot directly target a creature behind total cover

> A target with total cover can’t be targeted directly
>   by an attack or a spell, although some spells can reach
>   such a target by including it in an area of effect. A
>   target has total cover if it is completely concealed by
>   an obstacle.

Consider why you wouldn't be able to see the second target. If they are behind a wall, they have total cover and can't be targeted at all but still may be vulnerable to AoE abilities and spells. If they are invisible or otherwise hiding, then the "Unseen Attackers and Targets" section comes in to play and you can attack with disadvantage

> When you attack a target that you can’t see, you have
>   disadvantage on the attack roll. This is true whether
>   you’re guessing the target’s location or you’re targeting
>   a creature you can hear but not see.

Do keep in mind though that the rules for cover state that the benefits are conferred when the attack originates on the opposite side of the cover

> A target can benefit from cover only when an
>   attack or other effect originates on the opposite side
>   of the cover.