# How does cover interact with the Arcane Archer's Curving Shot?

Tags: dnd-5e, class-feature, fighter, ranged-attack, cover

One of the features of the Arcane Archer fighter subclass is Curving Shot:

> At 7th level, you learn how to direct an errant arrow toward a new target. When you make an attack roll with a magic arrow and miss, you can use a bonus action to reroll the attack roll against a different target within 60 feet of the original target. [XGtE, pg. 28]

How does this interact with cover?

The PHB description of cover says, among other things:

> A target can benefit from cover only when an attack or other effect originates on the opposite side of the cover. [PHB, pg. 196]

So what's the origin of a Curving Shot attack?  I see two possibilities:

1. The origin of the redirected attack is the original, missed target.
2. The origin remains at the archer.

---

Related:

[Does the Arcane Archer fighter's Curving Shot feature require you to see the second creature if you missed the first?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/146993/does-the-arcane-archer-fighters-curving-shot-feature-require-you-to-see-the-sec)

[How does range interact with the Arcane Archer's Curving Shot?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/187905/how-does-range-interact-with-the-arcane-archers-curving-shot)

---

Answer (score 3):

## Ask your DM.

I do not think there is anything RAW that would address this directly.

On the one hand, Curved Shot says you "reroll the attack roll", which might indicate that the new attack would originate from the archer.

However thematically, the shot has been fired, and Curved Shot says it is directing "an errant arrow towards a new target", which might indicate that the arrow is being redirected from wherever it is, possibly negating cover.

As a DM and in the spirit of preserving the flavour of an Arcane Archer using their innate magical abilities to redirect an arrow, I would rule that the Curved Shot originates from wherever it happens to be after it has missed its target. Whether this negates cover would be up to the DM, and I would rule depending on where the missed enemy is.