# How does range interact with the Arcane Archer's Curving Shot?

Tags: dnd-5e, class-feature, fighter, ranged-attack

One of the features of the Arcane Archer fighter subclass is Curving Shot:

> At 7th level, you learn how to direct an errant arrow toward a new target. When you make an attack roll with a magic arrow and miss, you can use a bonus action to reroll the attack roll against a different target within 60 feet of the original target. [XGtE, pg. 28]

How does this interact with range?

The Player's Handbook describes range as follows:

> The range lists two numbers. The first is the weapon’s normal range in feet, and the second indicates the weapon’s maximum range. When attacking a target beyond normal range, you have disadvantage on the attack roll. You can’t attack a target beyond the weapon’s long range. [PHB, pg. 147]

I see at least four ways this might interact with Curving Shot:

1. **The distance between the old target and new target is added to the shot's original range.**  This may extend the range to beyond normal (in which case the new attack role must be made at disadvantage) or beyond maximum (in which case the new target is not valid).
2. **The range of the redirected shot is only the distance between the old target and new target.**  The shot has a new point of origin at the old target, so the new range will be between 0 and 60 feet, as limited by Curving Shot.
3. **The range of the redirected shot is the distance between the archer and the new target.**  If the new target is farther from the archer than the old one was, the range will be larger; if the new target is closer, the range will be smaller.
4. **The range between the archer and old target is all that matters.** As long as the distance from the old target to the new target is within the 60 feet defined in Curving Shot, the initial range between the archer and the old target is all that matters.  The initial attack is rerolled as is.

---

*Related*

[How does cover interact with the Arcane Archer's Curving Shot?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/187904/how-does-cover-interact-with-the-arcane-archers-curving-shot)

[Does the Arcane Archer fighter's Curving Shot feature require you to see the second creature if you missed the first?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/146993/does-the-arcane-archer-fighters-curving-shot-feature-require-you-to-see-the-sec)

---

Answer (score 2):

## Ask your DM

In general, things only do what they say the do, and the specific outweighs the general.

On range:

> When attacking a target beyond normal range, you have disadvantage on the attack roll. You can’t attack a target beyond the weapon’s long range.

**RAW:** The original attack must be made against a creature within the weapon's range, or else there will be disadvantage on the attack roll.

If the attack misses, the Arcane Archer can use their Curving Shot ability to

> reroll the attack roll against a different target within 60 feet of the original target.

**RAW:** So long as the new target is within 60ft of the original target, the Curving Shot ability works as described. There would not be disadvantage on this attack since Curved Shot does not say there would be disadvantage imposed. However, since you are rerolling the attack roll, if the original attack had disadvantage so too would the reroll.

**RAI (and what I would do):** This may allow an Arcane Archer to extend the range of their missed attack by 60ft, but I think this also fits thematically with the Arcane Archer as a fighter imbuing magic into their archery.

Comment: So you're arguing that option #4 from my question is the correct interpretation?

Comment: Why "Ask your DM"?  Your answer doesn't otherwise seem to indicate a need for a subjective ruling.

Comment: @gto I don't think this is something that is clear cut according to RAW. Though my RAI would align with RAW I could also see another DM ruling differently.